# C++ CSV line with commas and strings within double quotes

Tags: c++, csv, double-quotes

I'm reading a CSV file in C++ and the row format is as such:

"Primary, Secondary, Third", "Primary", , "Secondary", 18, 4, 0, 0, 0

(notice the empty value)

When I do:

```
while (std::getline(ss, csvElement, ',')) {
   csvColumn.push_back(csvElement);
}
```

This splits up the first string into pieces which isn't correct.

How do I preserve the string when iterating? I tried to do a combination of the above and while also grabbing the lines separated by double quote but I got wild results.

Comment: Does anyone have a good solution for this using `std::quoted`? The standard specifically mentions CSV files when describing `std::quoted` but I can't come up with an elegant way to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to interpret the comma depending on whether you're betwwen the quote or not.  This is too complexfor `getline()`.

The solution would be to read the full line with `getline()`, and parse the line by iterating through the string character by character, and maintaing an indicator whether you're between double quotes or not.

Here is a first "raw" example (double quotes are not removed in the fields and escape characters are not interpreted):

```
string line; 
while (std::getline(cin, line)) {        // read full line
    const char *mystart=line.c_str();    // prepare to parse the line - start is position of begin of field
    bool instring{false};                
    for (const char* p=mystart; *p; p++) {  // iterate through the string
        if (*p=='"')                        // toggle flag if we're btw double quote
            instring = !instring;     
        else if (*p==',' && !instring) {    // if comma OUTSIDE double quote
            csvColumn.push_back(string(mystart,p-mystart));  // keep the field
            mystart=p+1;                    // and start parsing next one
        }
    }
csvColumn.push_back(string(mystart));   // last field delimited by end of line instead of comma
}
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/5Wvmv9)

Answer (score 7):

Using `std::quoted` allows you to read quoted strings from input streams.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "\"Primary, Secondary, Third\", \"Primary\", , \"Secondary\", 18, 4, 0, 0, 0";

    while (ss >> std::ws) {
        std::string csvElement;

        if (ss.peek() == '"') {
            ss >> std::quoted(csvElement);
            std::string discard;
            std::getline(ss, discard, ',');
        }
        else {
            std::getline(ss, csvElement, ',');
        }

        std::cout << csvElement << "\n";
    }
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/Im5B2g)

The caveat is that quoted strings are only extracted if the first non-whitespace character of a value is a double-quote. Additionally, any characters after the quoted strings will be discarded up until the next comma.

Comment: As per my comment on the question, I feel like there should be a good way to utilise `std::quoted` for CSV parsing. Let me know if you have any improvement upon this.

Comment: According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted, cin skips whitespace by default, and `quoted` extracts the first character via `stream >> c`, so it works even if there's whitespace between the comma and the opening quote. As such, you don't need the peek.

Comment: @MooingDuck If whitespace is skipped by default then always calling `std::quoted` will split un-quoted strings containing whitespace, potentially before the comma separator. I'm not sure if that will fail to parse typical CSV formats? Or maybe I have misunderstood your suggestion.

Comment: Yup, you're right, I'm wrong.  Hmm. It's weird that it seems so inept at solving it's own task

Comment: @MooingDuck I agree, it feels like I'm missing something! I suppose it is handy for writing CSV files at least.

Comment: RFC4180-compliant CSV files double their double-quotes to escape them, so the call to `quoted` above should look like `std::quoted(csvElement, '"', '"')`.  Also regarding the `discard` bit, according to that same RFC a field is either fully enclosed in double-quotes, or don't have double quote in it, so if you want to be strict and reject non-RFC-compliant CSV files you could just expect a comma after a quoted field.

Comment: I believe instead of doing `std::getline` with the `discard` string you could do `ss.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ',');`

Answer (score 0):

> How do I preserve the string when iterating?

Here is the C++ approach I have used.

I noticed that you have only 3 field types: string, null, and int.

The following approach uses these field types (in method "void init()"), in the order each each row presents the fields, sometimes using string::find() ( instead of getline() ) to locate field end.

Each of the 3 methods consumes characters from the string with erase.  I know erase is slow, but I made this choice for my convenience. (erasing is easier to test, just add a cout after each extract).  The erase's can be removed / replaced by appropriate handling (where needed) of start-of-search index.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <cassert>


class CSV_t
{
   typedef std::vector<int>  IntVec_t;

   // private nested class -- holds contents of 1 csv record
   class CSVRec_t
   {
   public:
      std::string primary;
      std::string secondary;
      std::string nullary;
      std::string thirdary;
      IntVec_t    i5;

      std::string show()
         {
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss <<            std::setw(25) << primary
               << "     " << std::setw(10) << secondary
               << "     " << std::setw(12)<< thirdary << "     ";

            for (size_t i=0;
                 i<i5.size(); ++i) ss << std::setw(5) << i5[i];

            ss << std::endl;
            return (ss.str());
         }

   }; // class CSVRec_t


   typedef std::vector<CSVRec_t> CSVRecVec_t;

   CSVRecVec_t csvRecVec;  // holds all csv record

public:

   CSV_t() { };

   void init(std::istream& ss)
      {
         do  // read all rows of file
         {
            CSVRec_t csvRec;

            std::string s;
            (void)std::getline(ss, s);

            if(0 == s.size()) break;

            assert(s.size()); extractQuotedField(s, csvRec.primary);   // 1st quoted substring
            assert(s.size()); extractQuotedField(s, csvRec.secondary); // 2nd quoted substring
            assert(s.size()); confirmEmptyField(s, csvRec.nullary);    // null field
            assert(s.size()); extractQuotedField(s, csvRec.thirdary);  // 3rd quoted substring
            assert(s.size()); extract5ints(s, csvRec.i5);              // handle 5 int fields

            csvRecVec.push_back(csvRec);  // capture

            if(ss.eof()) break;

         }while(1);
      }

   void show()
      {
         std::cout << std::endl;

         for (size_t i = 0; i < csvRecVec.size(); ++i)
            std::cout << std::setw(5) << i+1 << "   " << csvRecVec[i].show();

         std::cout << std::endl;
      }

private:

   void extractQuotedField(std::string& s, std::string& s2)
      {
         size_t indx1 = s.find('"', 0);
         assert(indx1 != std::string::npos);

         size_t indx2 = s.find('"', indx1+1);
         assert(indx2 != std::string::npos);

         size_t rng1 = indx2 - indx1 + 1;

         s2 = s.substr(indx1, rng1);

         s.erase(indx1, rng1+1);
      }

   void confirmEmptyField(std::string& s, std::string nullary)
      {
         size_t indx1 = s.find('"');

         nullary = s.substr(0, indx1);

         // tbd - confirm only spaces and comma's in this substr()

         s.erase(0, indx1); 
      }

   void extract5ints(std::string& s, IntVec_t& i5)
      {
         std::stringstream ss(s);

         int t = 0;
         for (int i=0; i<5; ++i)
         {
            ss >> t;
            ss.ignore(1); // skip ','
            assert(!ss.bad()); // confirm ok
            i5.push_back(t);
         }
         s.erase(0, std::string::npos);
      }

};  // class CSV_t



int t288(void) // test 288
{
   std::stringstream ss;
   ss << "\"Primary, Secondary, Third\", \"Primary\", , \"Secondary\", 18, 4, 0, 0, 0\n"
      << "\"Pramiry, Secandory, Thrid\", \"Pramiry\", , \"Secandory\", 19, 5, 1, 1, 1\n"
      << "\"Pri-mary, Sec-ondary, Trd\", \"Pri-mary\", , \"Sec-ondary\", 20, 6, 2, 3, 4\n"
      << std::endl;

   CSV_t csv;

   csv.init(ss);

   csv.show(); // results

   return (0);
}
```