# C++11 equivalent to std::quoted introduced in C++14

Tags: c++, c++11, double-quotes

As used in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35639947/8196393), I'm looking for a C++11 compatible code for the same but the usage of `std::quoted` prevents me from achieving that. Can anyone suggest an alternative solution?

Comment: Write your own implementation of `quoted` (a useful function in many scenarios).

Comment: @n.m. That would be my last resort. Right now, I'd really like a quicker alternative solution.

Comment: Copy an existing implementation? e.g. [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/iomanip#L461) and [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/quoted_string.h#L49).

Comment: @Jesse: Quicker? It shouldn't take more than *five minutes* to code.

Comment: I just did a very simple implementation of the output part of std::quoted, if you want: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/41626fb5b443cc33 - this took just a few minutes. I leave you the input part as a exercice !

Comment: How many people can type [~200LOC](https://github.com/boostorg/io/blob/develop/include/boost/io/detail/quoted_manip.hpp) in five minutes?

Comment: Actually 5 mins is quite fast if you don't know the specifications / just discovered the function 5 mins earlier ;) (that's 2 lines every 3 seconds).

Comment: @cpplearner I would reformulate this question into "How many people can type ~200 lines of **correct** code in five minutes?" ;-) Personally, I'm definitely outside of that group.

Comment: @Synxis: Your code does the wrong thing on `std::string`s with embedded nulls

Comment: @Eric Yes, but the changes are trivial. And putting `\0` in the middle of strings is a big WTF in itself

Answer (score -1):

I give my answer assuming that you expect to find a generic approach to handle such situations. The main question that defines the guideline for me is:
*"How long am I supposed to maintain this code for an older compiler version?"*

1. If I'm certain that it will be migrated to the newer toolset along with the rest of the code base (even though in a few years time, but it will inevitably happen), then I just copy-paste implementation from the standard headers *of the next target version of my compiler* and put it into `namespace std` in a separate header within my code base. Even though it's a very rude hack, it ensures that I have exactly the same code version as the one I'll get after migration. As I start using newer (in this case C++14-compatible) compiler, I will just remove my own `"quoted.h"`, and that's it.

**Important Caveat**: [Barry suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266325/c11-equivalent-to-stdquoted-introduced-in-c14#comment77495636_45266325) to copy-paste gcc's implementation, and I agree as long as the `gcc` is your main target compiler. If that's not the case, then I'd take the one from your compiler. I'm making this statement explicitly because I had troubles when I tried to copy gcc's `std::nested_exception` into my code base and, having switched from Visual Studio 2013 to 2017, noticed several differences. Also, in the case of `gcc`, pay attention to its license.

2. If I'm in a situation where I'll have to maintain compatibility with this older compiler for quite a while (for instance, if my product targets multiple compiler version), then it's more preferable first of all to look if there's a similar functionality available in Boost. And there is, in most cases. So check out [at Boost website](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/io/doc/quoted_manip.html). Even though it states

> "Quoted" I/O Manipulators for Strings are not yet accepted into Boost
>   as public components. Thus the header file is currently located in

you are able to use it from "boost/detail". And, I strongly believe that it's still better than writing your own version (despite the [advice from Synxis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266325/c11-equivalent-to-stdquoted-introduced-in-c14#comment77495910_45266325)), even though the latter can be quite simple.

3. If you're obliged to maintain the old toolset **and** you cannot use Boost, well...then it's maybe indeed worth thinking of putting your own implementation in.