# Bug in Visual Studio with std::quoted

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, language-lawyer

Just making sure that it is indeed a bug and not something I might have misunderstood about the functionality of [std::quoted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted)

Here is the code that should in my opinion escape double quotes with double quotes and then unescape them back to the original string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string s = R"(something"something)";
    std::cout << "Original: \t" << s << std::endl;

    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << std::quoted(s, '"', '"');
    std::string s1 = oss.str();
    std::cout << "Quoted: \t" << s1 << std::endl;

    std::istringstream iss(s1);
    std::string s2;
    iss >> std::quoted(s2, '"', '"');
    std::cout << "Unquoted: \t" << s2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The expected output:

```
Original:   something"something
Quoted:     "something""something"
Unquoted:   something"something
```

However this is what I get in VS2017 15.6.6:

```
Original:   something"something
Quoted:     "something""something"
Unquoted:   something
```

Could anyone confirm this is a bug?

**UPDATE:**

Good news everyone. The [ticket I filed with MS](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/241210/stdquoted-behaviour-is-inconsitent-when-delim-esca.html) got marked as `fixed`.

Comment: Both libstdc++ and libc++ exhibit the behavior you expect, but I'm not sure from my reading of [the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/quoted.manip#3) what the expected behavior when `delim == escape` is. I don't see anything saying to prefer considering a char as a delimiter or as an escape. VS2017 seems to prefer a delimiter, whereas libstdc++ and libc++ don't.

Comment: @Justin Thank you for the reference

Comment: I'd say that it's a defect in the standard, the case `delim==escape` is quite common, it should be at very least specified in some way.

Answer (score 5):

After further research into this problem I would like to answer my own question. Thanks to @Justin and @MatteoItalia for the insightful comments. In short, this is not a bug but rather an undefined behaviour, as VC++ seems to follow the [standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/quoted.manip#3) to the dot, while other compilers taking liberties to interpret it in own way, because there is no strict guideline on how to deal with cases of `delim == escape`, and this [paragraph](http://eel.is/c++draft/quoted.manip#3.1.1.3) doesn't explain it:

> Until an unescaped delim character is reached or !in, extract
>   characters from in and append them to s, except that if an escape is
>   reached, ignore it and append the next character to s.

This is exactly what is happening with VC++, the first double quote `"` after `something` is interpreted as unescaped delim character rather than escape character, which terminates the routine. IMO it needs clarification, something like: *If escape character is found, check if it is followed by delim character and if so, discard escape character.* Here is [original proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3654.html) I think.

I have filed a [report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/241210/stdquoted-behaviour-is-inconsitent-when-delim-esca.html) at MS bug tracker, but not much hope for the fix TBH. Then I found [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266325/c11-equivalent-to-stdquoted-introduced-in-c14) where @Barry suggests to use existing implementation [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/quoted_string.h#L49) and [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/iomanip#L461) from GCC, and this is exactly what I did.

This works as expected for me, but if you have any concerns or suggestions please do share.

Comment: Ensure you fix the names used by libstdc++. `_Quoted_string` is a reserved identifier (similarly, names like `__something` are reserved). Also, be sure you adhere to the license of libstdc++ (it [seems to be LGPL](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/COPYING.LIB))

Comment: If you want a more permissive license, use libc++; it's dual MIT + UIUC: https://libcxx.llvm.org/

Comment: A plain reading of that paragraph actually makes it clear that VC++ is doing the wrong thing when it encounters the `""`; the ambiguity comes when you reach the *end* of the stream. "Until A do B, except if C do D" is defining a general rule w/an exceptional case that can be tested for and must override A/B. The defects are that: 1. The behavior when the escape is the last character in a stream is undefined (there is no "next character") and 2. as you noted, by making `escape` escape *anything*, not just `delim`, using the same character for both means an "open quote" quotes until (past?) EOF.