# Can std::wistringstream ignore spaces within strings when parsing?

Tags: c++, string, parsing, visual-c++

`std::wistringstream` is a great way to easily parse lines from files.

However, there is one use case that it doesn't seem to be able to handle :

When parsing a `std::wstring`, it will consider any space in the string as the end of said string.

For example, if my file contains these lines :

> This_is_a_test 42
>
> Bad string name 747

If I attempt to parse a string and number, first one will succeed but the second one will fail.

If I change the file content with the following :

> "This_is_a_test" 42
>
> "Bad string name" 747

The parsing of the second string will still fail despite the `"`. Is there a trick to make the `std::wistringstream` ignore spaces within the string ? Something similar in principle to the `"`.

Is it a use case that this parsing method cannot handle ?

Code sample to try and parse the file :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
  // Open file
  std::wifstream file("D:\\file.txt", std::fstream::in);

  std::wstring str;
  double number;

  std::wstring line;

  // For each line
  while (getline(file, line))
  {
    std::wistringstream iss(line);

    // We parse the line
    if (!(iss >> str >> number))
      std::wcout << L"The line " << line << L" is NOT properly formatted" << std::endl;
    else
      std::wcout << L"The line " << line << L" is properly formatted" << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output with the examples presented :

> The line This_is_a_test 42 is properly formatted
>
> The line Bad string name 747 is NOT properly formatted

and

> The line "This_is_a_test" 42 is properly formatted
>
> The line "Bad string name" 747 is NOT properly formatted

Comment: And then, how would you want to prevent `this is a test 42` to be read as `"this is a test 42"`?

Comment: It wouldn't because there would be a closing `"` at the end of the string. (just like in my example `"this is a test" 42`.

Comment: Well, referred to the non-quotes idea - quotes would be fine, but are not supported. Python: 'hello"world' is a string literal equivalent to C++ "hello\"world", or consider XML-Tags. Problem is that there are too many ways one could do it (special separator characters included, compare to CSV), it would not be appropriate for a general purpose library to tie down to one specific solution...

Comment: Sometimes when you have particular requirements you just have to write the code yourself instead of expecting standard libraries to have written it for you.

Comment: Well it does seem like a pretty common use case and the standard libraries does handle it according to @Jarod42 's answer since C++14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might do, with [`std::quoted`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted), since C++14:

```
iss >> std::quoted(str);
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/7XTIGz)

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for ! Sadly can't use C++14 right now but I'll definitly use this solution when I can :D

Comment: You might look at [c11-equivalent-to-stdquoted-introduced-in-c14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266325/c11-equivalent-to-stdquoted-introduced-in-c14) which give links of actual implementations.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it !